# Using Custom Types with Boost Program Options

Tags: c++, boost, command-line-arguments, boost-program-options

I am trying to use Boost ProgramOptions to parse a config file to initialize my own class type Dataset (code below)

I am adding the option as:

```
config_.add_options()("dataset", po::value<Dataset>()->required(),"Dataset");
```

My Dataset class is defined as following:

```
#ifndef DATASET_H_
#define DATASET_H_

#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

class Dataset {
public:
  enum Name {
    JAVA, SUMATRA, ASIA, AFRICA
  };

  Dataset(Name name = JAVA) : name_(name) {}
  operator Name () const {return name_;}

  std::string asString() const;

private:
  Name name_;

  //prevent automatic conversion for any other built-in types such as bool, int, etc
  template<typename T>
  operator T() const;
};

inline std::string Dataset::asString() const {
  if (name_ == Dataset::JAVA)
    return "JAVA";
  else if (name_ == Dataset::SUMATRA)
    return "SUMATRA";
  else if (name_ == Dataset::ASIA)
    return "ASIA";
  else if (name_ == Dataset::AFRICA)
    return "AFRICA";
  else
    return "UNKNOWN DATASET";
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dataset& dataset) {
  os << dataset.asString();
  return os;
}

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Dataset& dataset) {
  std::string token;
  in >> token;
  if (boost::iequals(token, "java"))
    dataset = Dataset::JAVA;
  else if (boost::iequals(token, "sumatra"))
    dataset = Dataset::SUMATRA;
  else if (boost::iequals(token, "asia"))
    dataset = Dataset::ASIA;
  else if (boost::iequals(token, "africa"))
    dataset = Dataset::AFRICA;
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Dataset Name");
  return in;
}

#endif // DATASET_H_
```

I thought I have done everything, atleast this is what required to make boost happy for my other custom types. But I am getting this compile error, which I cannot comprehend:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_right_shift.hpp:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:171,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 ~/ProgramOptions.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::operator_exists<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, Dataset>::value’:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:179:4:   instantiated from ‘const bool boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::trait_impl1<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, Dataset, boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::dont_care, false>::value’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:214:4:   instantiated from ‘const bool boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::trait_impl<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, Dataset, boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::dont_care>::value’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:221:1:   instantiated from ‘boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, Dataset, boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::dont_care>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:394:1:   instantiated from ‘boost::detail::deduce_target_char_impl<boost::detail::deduce_character_type_later<Dataset> >’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:420:89:   instantiated from ‘boost::detail::deduce_target_char<Dataset>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:679:92:   instantiated from ‘boost::detail::lexical_cast_stream_traits<std::basic_string<char>, Dataset>’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2339:19:   instantiated from ‘static Target boost::detail::lexical_cast_do_cast<Target, Source>::lexical_cast_impl(const Source&) [with Target = Dataset, Source = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:2519:50:   instantiated from ‘Target boost::lexical_cast(const Source&) [with Target = Dataset, Source = std::basic_string<char>]’
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:89:13:   instantiated from ‘void boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<charT> >&, T*, long int) [with T = Dataset, charT = char]’
/usr/include/boost/program_options/detail/value_semantic.hpp:170:13:   instantiated from ‘void boost::program_options::typed_value<T, charT>::xparse(boost::any&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<charT> >&) const [with T = Dataset, charT = char]’
~/ProgramOptions.cpp:276:1:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:158:4: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::make [with T = std::basic_istream<wchar_t>]() >> boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::make [with T = Dataset]()’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:158:4: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<wchar_t>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:126:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<wchar_t>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:133:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<wchar_t>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:241:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = wchar_t, _Traits = std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t>]
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hpp:70:13: note: boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::no_operator boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::operator>>(const boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::any&, const boost::detail::has_right_shift_impl::any&)
```

Note: It does compile if I remove my type safety for my Dataset class, i.e remove the

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const;
```

**Update:**
With excellent advice from @Arne Mertz, I modidied my Dataset class to be as following

```
class Dataset {
public:
  enum Name {
    JAVA, SUMATRA, ASIA, AFRICA
  };

  Dataset(const Name& name = JAVA) : name_(name) {}
  Dataset(const Dataset& dataset) : name_(dataset.name_) {}

  Dataset& operator=(const Dataset& dataset) {name_ = dataset.name_;  return *this; }
  bool operator==(const Dataset& dataset) const { return name_ == dataset.name_; }
  bool operator!=(const Dataset& dataset) const { return name_ != dataset.name_; }

  Name name() const {return name_;}

  std::string asString() const;

private:
  Name name_;
};
```

This I guess provides some of my desired type-safety like:

```
Dataset d(1); // Should be error
Dataset d = Dataset::JAVA; // Should be fine
double val = d; // Should be error
if(d == Dataset::SUMATRA) {} // should be fine
if(d == 3) {} // Should be error
```

Comment: What is that `operator T()` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: Making that private prevents automatic conversion from bool or ints like Dataset d = 2; or if(d) {}.

Comment: @iNFINITEi the `oparator T()` converts `Dataset` to something else, not the other way round. e.g. `Dataset d; double x = d;` or like in this case it enables `any_unary_function(d)` for any function that takes one argument, regardless of its type - because the Dataset can eb converted to any type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The templated `operator T()` is the reason, and the workings of how the compiler does lookup for the `operator>>`:

Somewhere deep in the guts of boost, there is something like `is >> some_dataset`. Since it is in the boost namespace, and not in yours, the compiler **first** looks if there is a proper operator inside the accessible boost namespaces or a member operator in the `istream` class, that can be called without type conversions. Obviously there is not.
As a **second** approach, it looks if there are such operators accessible *with* a type conversion. Enters your "convert me to everything" operator and the different overloads of `istream::operator>>` you see as "candidates" in the error message. The overloads accept different types of function pointers and streambuf pointers, and since your class is convertible to *any* of those, the compiler does not know whether it shall convert the Dataset to a `streambuf*` or something else.
As a **third** option, i.e. when the `operator T()` is *not* present, the compiler does argument dependent lookup (ADL), meaning it scans the namespaces of both arguments (i.e. `namespace std` for the `istream` and your namespace for the `Dataset`) and finds the proper `operator>>` in your namespace, so it works if you don't declare that conversion operator.

This is a perfect example of why allowing implicit conversions can be problematic and should be avoided - even more if it is an implicit conversion to *anything* like your `operator T()`.

One solution could be to make the conversion operator `explicit` (C++11 only), probably even better would be a named conversion function. An alternative could be restricting the types a `Dataset` can be converted into vía `std::enable_if`, or by explicitly writing each non-templated conversion operator if there are only a few target types.